# Unit of lat/long given by google map api

Tags: google-maps-api-3, gps, latitude-longitude, units-of-measurement

I have given an address to google map api like **"21511 CONGRESS SPRINGS RD, Saratoga"** and api gives me corresponding lat/lng of this address as:

`latitude=37.252165 and longitude=-122.056565`, I need to know the unit of these latitude and longitude, are they in radians?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Now they are in degrees. But you can convert them in radians by adding this code:

```
google.maps.LatLng.prototype.latRadians = function()
{
   return (Math.PI * this.lat()) / 180;
}
google.maps.LatLng.prototype.lngRadians = function()
{
   return (Math.PI * this.lng()) / 180;
}
```

To know more about this you can visit: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng

If you have any more doubt please comment.

Suyash